# Weka OneClass Classifier Prediction Error using Java

Tags: java, weka

When using the following statement for predicting the class in OneClassClassifier

```
classifier.classifyInstance(newTestData.instance(i));
```

I am always getting 0.0 as the distribution. i.e. I never get to know whether it's an outlier or not.

The interesting thing is the Evaluation class gives the model accuracy along with the Unclassified Instances while building.

But while predicting it doesn't provide anything except 0 using the same model !

Comment: classifyInstance returns the index of the mkst probable class. Use distribution for instance to obtain confidences for all classes

Comment: On using classifier.distributionForInstance it provides me with an array contaning single value "1.0".

I understand that this means all my instances are predicted under the same category. But Why?

Shouldn't be some of them be left as Unclassified Instances.